Is there an efficient way to shade a specific area under a Graphics command?
long time Mathematica user, first time question asker on this forum...
I have the following diagram (code included for reference) and want to shade just the area marked as A:

I know how to shade between curves when using the Plot command, but is there a simple way anyone knows to do this under the Graphics command?
I've read the online documentation but nothing obvious jumped out at me - hence my asking here.
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Please post the Mathematica code.

It is in the image, but will post again as an edit.

a1 = Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]}]];
a2 = Region[Disk[{2, 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]}]];
a3 = Region[Disk[{2 Cos[\[Pi]/6], 2 Sin[\[Pi]/6]}, 2]];
RegionPlot[
 RegionDifference[
  RegionIntersection[a1, a3],
  a2],
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}]


Or...
a1 = Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]}]];
a2 = Region[Disk[{2, 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]}]];
a3 = Region[Disk[{2 Cos[\[Pi]/6], 2 Sin[\[Pi]/6]}, 2]];
RegionPlot[
 {RegionDifference[
   RegionIntersection[a1, a3],
   a2], RegionBoundary[a1], RegionBoundary[a2],
  RegionBoundary[a3]},
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {0, 6}}]


Or....
a1 = Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]}]];
a2 = Region[Disk[{2 , 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]}]];
a3 = Region[
   Disk[{2 Cos[\[Pi]/6], 2 Sin[\[Pi]/6]}, 2, {\[Pi]/6, 7 \[Pi]/6}]];
RegionPlot[
 {RegionDifference[
   RegionIntersection[a1, a3],
   a2], RegionBoundary[a1], RegionBoundary[a2],
  RegionBoundary[a3]},
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {0, 6}}]



Thanks - I decided to combine your code with mine using Show and it works well. I'm still wondering if this can be achieved within the Graphics command rather than RegionPlot, but it probably doesn't really matter.

You can also define implicit regions. In the following the semicircles are generated from the radii,centres and starting angle. The label location is generated using RegionCentroid. You could use Disk and EdgeForm and FaceForm etc for other ways.
ctr = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {Sqrt[3], 1}}
a0 = {0, 0, Pi/6};
semi[r_, c_, a_] := 
 Sequence[{Line[{c - r {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, c + r {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], 
   Circle[c, r, {a, a + Pi}]}]
reg = x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && (x - 2)^2 + y^2 >= 
   4 && (x - Sqrt[3])^2 + (y - 1)^2 <= 4
ctd = ImplicitRegion[reg, {x, y}] // RegionCentroid;
RegionPlot[reg, {x, -2, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {MapThread[semi[2, #1, #2] &, {ctr, a0}], Text["A", ctd]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 40, Frame -> False] 


